# Arithmetic gives unexpected value in ruby

Tags: ruby, math

Why is this:

```
((256-438)^2)+((227-298)^2)
```

Giving me `-253` when it should be `38165` instead?

Comment: Where are you computing this??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`^` is the bitwise exclusive OR operator (XOR)

`**` is the exponent operator, use:

```
((256-438)**2)+((227-298)**2)
```

Answer (score 6):

Because `^` is the operator for XOR, not exponents. Try `**` instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
Try ((256-438)**2)+((227-298)**2)
```

Answer (score 2):

`^` is the bitwise XOR operator, according to http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/language.html.  Not the "power of" operator.

Answer (score 2):

`^` is the XOR operator, not exponeniation.

Answer (score 0):

Use `**` not `^`

Code should be - `((256-438)**2)+((227-298)**2)`

`**` is the Exponentiation or 'power of' operator.

> **The Exponentiation operator**
>
> Raises `number` to the power of `second number`, which may be negative
>   or fractional.
>
> `2 ** 3 #=> 8`
>
> `2 ** -1 #=> (1/2)`
>
> `2 ** 0.5 #=> 1.4142135623731`

`^` is the bitwise XOR operator.

> **The XOR operator**
>
> The XOR operator implements an exclusive OR which means that it will
>   set the bit to 1 in the output if only one of the corresponding bits
>   in the inputs are set to 1:
>
> `(a = 18).to_s(2) #=> "10010"`
>
> `(b = 20).to_s(2) #=> "10100"`
>
> `(a ^ b).to_s(2) #=> "110"` (leading zeros are omitted)